# Move PictureBox using Timer

Tags: c#

My goal is to move a picturebox back and forth. My issue is how to do this.

I have written the following:

```
    int x = enemy.Location.X;
    int y = enemy.Location.Y;
    enemy.Location = new Point(x+-1, y);
```

This moves the picturebox off-screen, left. After moving left, I'd like it to move right, so that it moves back and forth - in a continuous loop.

The noob that I am, I tried:

```
    if (x < 40)
        enemy.Location = new Point(x - -100, y);
    else if (x > 400)
        enemy.Location = new Point(x - 5, y);
```

This proves unsuccessful - the box doesn't seem to move on reaching pixel 40.

Is there a simple solution that you can prod me towards, or have I dug an early grave for myself?!

I should specify: I am writing in C# per college assignment requirements.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

When moving left, when the x location reaches 0, change direction and move right.

When moving right, you need to use the width of the screen minus the width of your picturebox.

```
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth
```

edit:

Or better yet, use the width of your form minus the width of the picturebox. Then it will still work if its not maximized.

Comment: OK. I tried this, but get errors, so I must be slipping up somewhere. Here is my code. P.S. Isn't there a simple way to say 'Move left this many pixels > reach pixel 0 so Move Right > reach pixel e.g. 100 so Move Left' so a specified loop? P.S.S. thanks!         int x = enemy.Location.X;
        int y = enemy.Location.Y;
        enemy.Location = new Point(x+-1, y);
        if (x == 0)
            enemy.Location = ActiveForm.Width - enemy.Width;

Answer (score 0):

Setup a variable that toggles between negative and positive values to make it go left and right.  You toggle the direction by multiplying by -1.  Then you simply add that variable to the current X value like this:

```
    private int direction = -1; // this can be values other than 1 to make it jump farther each move

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = enemy.Location.X + direction;
        if (x <= 0)
        {
            direction = -1 * direction;
            x = 0;
        }
        else if (x >= this.ClientRectangle.Width - enemy.Width)
        {
            direction = -1 * direction;
            x = this.ClientRectangle.Width - enemy.Width;
        }
        enemy.Location = new Point(x, enemy.Location.Y);
    }
```

Comment: Should work but for better options to adjust speed I'd recommend keeping the coordinates in floats..